# Create a simple confirmation box in apps script to pop up in my html

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog

What is the correct way to pop up the alert/confirmation box in apps script. I used to be able to do it using javascript alert() or confirm() , but seems google has disabled it. So far the closest code i can get is below but still i can't make it to work.

I just want a simple yes/no dialog box.

**Code.gs**

```
function validate() {
  Browser.msgBox('Hello', Browser.Buttons.OK);  
}
function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<div>
 <form>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="validate()">
 </form>
</div>

<script>
  window.validate = function() {
    google.script.run.validate();
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

gs:

```
function validate() {
  return 'ok';  
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="validate()"/>
<div id="msg"></div>
<script>
  function validate() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(msg => document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = 'Server Says: ' + msg);
    .validate();
  }
</script>
</body>
```